# adding external javascript to html document

Tags: javascript, html

Hi so im trying to add my external js to a project and every-time i add my js and go to preview the project(its a calculator) my html is completely gone and all i have is the background. When i check the developer view i can see the html inside the script dropdown when i inspect the elements. Im not sure how to fix it ive tried putting the link to the js in other places besides the head with no luck.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
<script type="text/javascript"src="/Users/hailey/Documents/calculator.js" </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="calculator__display">0</div>
    <div class="calculator__keys">
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="add">+</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="subtract">-</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="multiply">&times;</button>
      <button class="key--operator" data-action="divide">÷</button>
      <button>7</button>
      <button>8</button>
      <button>9</button>
      <button>4</button>
      <button>5</button>
      <button>6</button>
      <button>1</button>
      <button>2</button>
      <button>3</button>
      <button>0</button>
      <button data-action="decimal">.</button>
      <button data-action="clear">AC</button>
      <button class="key--equal" data-action="calculate">=</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: _"Im not sure how to fix it"_ - By properly closing the `<script>` tag... `<script type="text/javascript"src="/Users/hailey/Documents/calculator.js" </script>` -> `<script type="text/javascript"src="/Users/hailey/Documents/calculator.js></script>"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the end >

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="/Users/hailey/Documents/calculator.js"> </script>

And at the bottom you need to switch <html> to </html>
```

Comment: Vote to close as this is obviously just a typo